# How can I rename files in a swift package in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I don't want to rename a swift package. I want to rename files in the swift package.  When I click on a file and wait until Xcode decides to bless me by highlighting the file so I can rename it, that moment never comes with Swift Packages.  [image]

Comment: This is not reproducible for me with Xcode 13.3.1. Apart from clicking a highlighted file you can display the File Inspector (Cmd-Opt-1) and change the filename there.

Comment: Are you trying to rename it in the original project where the package was created, or in the project into which you imported this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

one way is to open the file in Finder and rename it there. This would be problematic in a regular project, but because swift packages are just folders without a `.pbxproj` file, it works just fine.

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.

[image]

4.

[image]